# When Browsing on a Specific WFE, How do I Prevent Links From Directing me to the Public URL?

Tags: 2019, classic-experience

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Public URL | https://Public.my.domain |
| Web Front End 1 | WFE01.my.domain |
| Web Front End 2 | WFE02.my.domain |

When browsing with the address https://WFE02.my.domain, hover over any link.  The link will claim to be pointing at WFE02.  However, if I click a link the address goes to Public.my.domain.  How do I force users to stay on the WFE that they specified?  Being directed to Public.my.domain defeats the purpose of specifying the WFE.

Desired Result:

1. Go to: https://**WFE02**.my.domain.
2. Hover over any link the Top-Nav pointing to a page on the Web Application.
3. Link points to: https://**WFE02**.my.domain/some_page.aspx
4. Click that link
5. URL still starts with: https://**WFE02**.my.domain

Actual Results:

1. Go to: https://**WFE02**.my.domain.
2. Hover over any link the Top-Nav pointing to a page on the Web Application.
3. Link points to: https://**WFE02**.my.domain/some_page.aspx
4. Click that link
5. URL now starts with: https://**Public**.my.domain

> Update:

thanks to @lehuspohus, here is what I did:

1. Go to Alternate Access Mapping
2. Edit Public URLs (see table below)
3. Save
4. On the Alternate Access Mappings page
5. Click on each link under Internal URL(repeat 6-7 as needed
6. Change the Zone (see table below)
7. Click OK

| Zone | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Default | https://Public.my.domain |
| Intranet | WFE01.my.domain |
| Custom | WFE02.my.domain |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should add new AAM (via *Edit Public URLs* option): https://WFE02.my.domain.
So that both *Internal Url* and *Public URL* matches server name.

And remove mappings like `https://WFE02.my.domain (Internal) -> https://Public.my.domain (Public)` if any.

Comment: I add the steps to fix the issue, to my question.  I might not have done exactly what you said, but it worked.  Thank you